# SDL C++ Jumping

Tags: c++, sdl

```
const int jumpHeight             = 10;

//Non-Const variables
bool running                     = true;
bool isJumping                   = false;
bool isFalling                   = false;
int jump                         = 0;
Uint8 *keystate                  = NULL;

//Structs
typedef struct entity {
    SDL_Rect hitbox;
} playerType, enemyType;
playerType player;
enemyType basicEnemy[10];

//Main Function
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    while( running )
    {
            keystate = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
            if( keystate[SDLK_UP] )
            {
                    if(isJumping != true)
                    {
                            isJumping = true;
                    }
            }
            if( keystate[SDLK_LEFT] )  player.hitbox.x -= 1;
            if( keystate[SDLK_RIGHT] ) player.hitbox.y += 1;
            //Window collision
            if( player.hitbox.x < 0 ) {player.hitbox.x  = 0;}
            else if( player.hitbox.x > SCREEN_WIDTH  - player.hitbox.w ) {player.hitbox.x = SCREEN_WIDTH  - player.hitbox.w;}
            if( player.hitbox.y < 0 ) {player.hitbox.y  = 0;}
            else if( player.hitbox.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.hitbox.h ) {player.hitbox.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.hitbox.h;}

            //Jumping
            if( isJumping == true )
            {
                    if( jump >= jumpHeight || isFalling == true )
                    {
                            jump--;
                            player.hitbox.y--;
                            isFalling = true;
                    }else if( jump <= 0 && isFalling == true )
                    {
                            jump - 0;
                            isFalling = false;
                            isJumping = false;
                    }else {
                            jump++;
                            player.hitbox.y++;
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

This is my current code in my game (the parts related to jumping anyway). When I press the Up key my character goes to the top of the window and stays there. Where have I gone wrong?
I compile with `g++ -o myprogram.exe mysource.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`.
Walking you through how the code is supposed to work:
Press Up: isJumping becomes true, and then the player is raised to the max height, then goes down again to where it started (later I will add collision checking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's going to the top of the window because of this code here:

```
if (jump >= jumpHeight || isFalling == true) {
    jump--;
    player.hitbox.y--;
    isFalling = true;
}
```

Once this condition has been met, it will run for the rest of the loop and the conditions will never be false. To fix it, you need to check if `jump` is `0` after you decrement it. If it's `0`, set `isFalling` to false and `isJumping` to false.

Also, do note that when you increase the `y`, you're making the unit go lower on the window because SDL windows have origins starting from the top left corner and the Y axis is downward.

Replace all increments of `y` with decrements and vice versa.

Comment: With the y values, I originally did have it like that, but for some odd reason it required me to put it the way it is. When I implemented your fix I put them back to the original way and it worked!